# Selecta a parameter with a laravel query in according to 1 condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have this schema in my table on mysql:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNf9I.png)

I've saved in a variable $player_id the id player that in this table can be player_1 or player_2

in according to this parameter I want to retrieve the opponent player id, so if player_1 = player_id get player_2 else if player_2 = player_id get player_1. I've tryied with foreach but does'nt work well,

```
 public function RedirectToPersonal()
    {
        $torneo = Cache::get('torneo');
        //return $torneo;
        $player_id = DB::table('players')
            ->where('FirstName', '=', Auth::user()->firstName)
            ->where('LastName', '=', Auth::user()->lastName)
            ->value('player_id');

        $player_data = DB::table('tabella_' . $torneo)
            ->orderByDesc('CurrentRoundNumber')
            ->where('player_1', '=', $player_id)
            ->orWhere('player_2', '=', $player_id)
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
        //dump($player_data);

        foreach ($player_data as $key => $value) {
            if ($player_data[$key]->player_1 = $player_id) {
                $names[] = $player_data[$key]->player_2;
            } else {
                $names[] = $player_data[$key]->player_1;
            }
        }
        //dump($player_id);
        //dump($names);

        $data = [
            "player_data" => $player_data,
        ];
        return view('user.personal', $data);
```

I need as a if statement in my query builder.
How I can do it?

Comment: The given code has nothing to do with Laravel and Eloquent

Comment: @MattKomarnicki I show you just how I used foreach now I put all controller if you need

Answer (score 0):

Try using union:

```
$first = DB::table('tabella_' . $torneo)
            ->selectRaw('player_2 as opponent_id')
            ->where('player_1', $player_id);
 
$opponents = DB::table('tabella_' . $torneo)
            ->selectRaw('player_1 as opponent_id')
            ->where('player_2', $player_id);
            ->union($first)
            ->get();
```

And I believe that you can still get the correct results using your code. However, in if statement you need to use == to compare values. One more thing, you can use $value->player_1 instead:

```
   //...
   if ($value->player_1 == $player_id) {
   //...
```